# php REGEX to match custom url structure issue

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match, match

I tried the pattern below with a lot of variations of `(` `)` and `[` `]` but I couldn't achieved my aim.

```
$pattern = '/^http:\/\/www.mydomain.p.ht\/?[\p{L}\p{N}\-]{0,36}\/?[\p{L}\p{N}\-]{0,51}\/?[\p{L}\p{N}\-]{0,101}$/';
```

My aim is: to match my needed url structure

1. `http://www.mydomain.p.ht`
2. 0 or 1 `/` slash character
3. utf-8 aware letters, numbers and dash character. Total length is min
   0, max 36
4. 0 or 1 `/` slash character
5. utf-8 aware letters, numbers and dash character. Total length is min
   0, max 51
6. 0 or 1 `/` slash character
7. utf-8 aware letters, numbers and dash character. Total length is min
   0, max 101. there mustn't exist `/` slash character at the very end.

currently `http://www.mydomain.p.ht/1234561-234561234561234-56123456123456şğ` matches but it shouldn't since `1234561-234561234561234-56123456123456şğ` part has more than 36 characters.

Can you please correct my pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just correcting the regex itself

```
/^http:\/\/www.mydomain.p.ht(\/|\/[\p{L}\p{N}\-]{1,36}(\/|\/[\p{L}\p{N}\-]{1,51}(\/|\/[\p{L}\p{N}\-]{1,101})?)?)?$/
```

the issue is that making the `/` optional allows the regex to combine multiple of the [\p{L}\p{N}-] groups to match more then 36 or 51 chars and so forth.  I made one assumption, that you can't have `http://www.mydomain.p.ht//1234561-234561234561234-56123456123456şğ`, note the double `/`

For additional info, I highly reccommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: thank you so much. Golden shot. +1 for extra explanation. will be accepted after 5min.